# Match all characters after the last instance of a string in regex

Tags: regex

I am looking to capture all characters after the last instance of a string in regex.

The string (that which we're searching after the last instance of) is as follows, sans quotes: `" - "`, or `\b\s\-\s\b`: boundary(whitespace character, preceded by `-`, preceded by whitespace character).

Test string as follows:

`One Thing - Two Things - Three Things - Four Things`

Desired match:

`Four Things`

This regex only matches everything after the *first* instance of the string:

`(?<=\b\s\-\s\b)(.*)$`

(Returns, sans quotes: `"Two Things - Three Things - Four Things"`)

Whereas this matches everything after the last *single character* `-`:

`[^\-]+$`

(Returns, sans quotes: `" Four Things"`)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a positive lookbehind then negating on the `-` delimiter and taking the last result

`(?<=- )[^-]+$`

https://regex101.com/r/sMX9FC/1

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get your match without using lookarounds.

You could match any char except a newline from the start of the string followed by matching your pattern. That will match the last instance.

Then capture in a group matching 0+ times any char except a newline until the end of the string.

```
^.*\b\s\-\s\b(.*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*` Match any char except a newline
- `\b\s\-\s\b\` Match your pattern
- `(.*)` Capture in group 1 matching 0+ times any char except a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eSWwov/1)

The is no tool or programming language listed, but if `\K` is supported to forget what was matched, you might also use:

```
^.*\b\s\-\s\b\K.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eSWwov/2)

Answer (score 1):

This matches the end of a string, everything that is not a `-` after a `-`.

```
-\s*([^-]+)$
```

It's the simplest regex I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

`.*(?<=\b\s\-\s\b)(.*)$`, or putting a `.*` before your current regex [should achieve what you're after,](https://regex101.com/r/wRU0Nt/1) since that's a greedy match by default.

Comment: I don't really get it about the \b and didn't seem to go well in php... without it works for me `.*(?<=\s\-\s)(.*)$` (in javascript both work)

Comment: @AntonyGibbs It's a zero-length match on a word boundary. Not supported everywhere, but since it's given as an example by the OP I assume it's supported in the environment he's using.